# How to store the JSON returned from an HTTP request inside logic apps in Azure

Tags: azure, .net-core

Inside the logic app, I have created the HTTP request that will return the JSON from the REST API. Now I want to save that JSON, parse it, and save the results into a SQL Server db.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a table in sql server and there is a logic app action named  "SQL server" then you can map the data returned from the http request and write to sql server.
Here is a similar flow,

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/deeperinsights/2017/07/12/how-to-measure-twitter-sentiment-with-azure-logic-apps-sql-database-and-power-bi/

Comment: Unable to connect cognitive service through the logic apps. Getting error Please check your account info and/or permissions and try again.
Is this region issue when we have created the cognitive service.